# Как загрузить txt или html файл в string?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Нужно открыть в Android html (если надо, можно переименовать в txt) файл, его содержимое присвоить переменной String для некоторых манипуляций над его содержимым. Файл находится в папке assets. Файл пробовал сохранять в различных кодировках, сейчас UTF-8.
Пробовал вот такие методы открытия:

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("TripDetailActivity1.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());            
template = reader.toString();
```

Отлавливается такая ошибка:

> `java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed`

```
String template22 = Files.toString(new File("file:///android_asset/TripDetailActivity1.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Пробовал разные пути (без `file:///`, только с двумя `//`, клал файл на диск С в корень...)

Отлавливается такая ошибка:

> `...(No such file or directory)`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно указать путь, или может другой метод загрузки файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри данну статью: 
[understanding-assets](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-assets.html)

Вроде в ней не плохо расписана работа с файлами в assets. (строка 63-67)

Comment: Всем спасибо! Буду пробывать!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Надо использовать:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("TripDetailActivity1.txt");
```

Comment: Всем спасибо! Буду пробывать!!!!

Comment: Не пробывать, а пробОвать!

Comment: Проверочное слово "пробУй" значит пробУвать)

Comment: проверочное проба значит пробавать

Comment: Охренеть, неужели сложно попробОвать погуглить или хотя бы включить спелл чекер?

Comment: :) это шутка была, совсем заработался что ли?

Comment: Шутка была настолько прозрачна, что ее не было видно. Видимо, заработался :)

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема в компрессии, то варианты такие.

1. Использовать расширение для несжимаемых файлов (jpg, jpeg, png, gif, wav, mp2, mp3, ogg, aac, mpg, mpeg, mid, midi, smf, jet, rtttl, imy, xmf, mp4, m4a, m4v, 3gp, 3gpp, 3g2, 3gpp2, amr, awb, wma, wmv).
2. Отключить компрессию для интересующего типа файлов. Как это делается в Eclipse ADT неизвестно, а для скриптов в ant можно явно указать опцию aapt.